# Android: sync two mediaPlayers (play one after another) - remove gap

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, soundpool, android-audiomanager

I'm using in my app two mediaplayers. I want play first song (mp1) and then play second song (mp2). But there is a little gap/silence between these songs. Is it possible somehow remove?

I create MediaPlayers (mp1 and mp2) in OnCreate() method:

```
    mp1 = new MediaPlayer();
    mp1.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mp1.setOnCompletionListener(mySongCompletionListener1);

    mp2 = new MediaPlayer();
    mp2.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    mp1.setDataSource("/storage/emulated/0/IAMDJ/SAMPLES/Free Future Kits/Drop/WA FFHK Drop1.ogg");
    mp1.prepare();

    mp2.setDataSource("/storage/emulated/0/IAMDJ/SAMPLES/Free Future Kits/Verse/WA FFHK Verse1.ogg");
    mp2.prepare();
```

And:

```
private OnCompletionListener mySongCompletionListener1 = new OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp2.start(); //first song finished, start second...
    }
};
```

Note: I don´t want use SoundPool because it doesn't have seekTo().

Is it possible to remove the silence?

Comment: Have you considered using [`setNextMediaPlayer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setNextMediaPlayer(android.media.MediaPlayer)) ?

Comment: Thanks! It´s the solution.

Comment: I have one problem with it. When ends second MediaPlayer and I call again mp1.start() then nothing happend. I get "no active player". How can I play it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [setNextMediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setNextMediaPlayer(android.media.MediaPlayer)) (as Michael advised) is right and good solution.